# iOS Handle push notification when app is not running

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, push, handle

I'm trying to use push notifications for my app. It's working when the app is running or when it's in background. But if the user "kills" the app and if I send a push notification, when the user taps on the notification, the app doesn't open to handle it.

How can I do this? I want to call a specific view when the user taps on a notification.

In my function `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, I wrote this:

```
if (launchOptions != nil){
    [self callView];
}
```

I call the same function, `[self callView];`, in `didReceiveRemoteNotification:`. But it's not working unless the app is active or in the background.

Comment: Where would you get "launchOptions" in the case of didReceiveRemoteNotification? Seems like it would equal nil when the app isn't running in the background.

Comment: Nop, I didn't use 'launchOptions" in didReceiveRemoteNotification :)

Comment: Oh, I thought you put that code snippet in both. What did you put it didReceiveRemoteNotification then?

Comment: if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
// I'm showing an alert
} else {
[self callView];
}

Comment: Oh, so if the application is active, you're just showing an alert. Is that alert showing when you receive the notification?

Comment: Nevermind. I misunderstood your question. I'll update it to make the language clearer for others.

Comment: I'd like to edit your question to make it clearer but what do you mean by "I don't arrive to handle it"

Comment: When the app is active, I'm showing an alert to signal to the user there is a new notification.

Comment: No problem. I understood what you meant because I've seen other people complaining about the same problem lately... I think it's probably a bug, but I'll report back if I happen to see a solution.